# Using numpy.exp to calculate object life length

Tags: numpy, scipy, statistics, exponential

I can't find any example anywhere on the internet .

I would like to learn using the exponential law to calculate a probability.

This my exponential lambda : 0.0035

> 1. What is the probability that my object becomes defectuous before 100 hours of work ? P(X < 100)

How could I write this with numpy or sci kit ? Thanks !

**Edit : this is the math :**

P(X < 100) = 1 - e ** -0.0035 * 100 =  0.3 = 30%

**Edit 2 :**

Hey guys, I maybe have found something there, hi hi :
http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs109/cs109.1192/handouts/pythonForProbability.html

**Edit 3 :**

This is my attempt with scipy :

```
from scipy import stats
B = stats.expon(0.0035)   # Declare B to be a normal random variable
print(B.pdf(1))       # f(1), the probability density at 1
print(B.cdf(100))      # F(2) which is also P(B < 100)
print(B.rvs())        # Get a random sample from B
```

but B.cdf is wrong : it prints 1, while it should print 0.30, please help !
B.pdf prints 0.369 : What is this ?

**Edit 4 :** I've done it with the python math lib like this :

```
lambdaCalcul = - 0.0035 * 100
MyExponentialProbability = 1 - math.exp(lambdaCalcul)

print("My probability is",MyExponentialProbability  * 100 , "%");
```

Any other solution with numpy os scipy is appreciated, thank you

Comment: Why do you need numpy for this? This is evaluating the cummulative probability distribution.

Comment: Hello, if you have a solution with math, ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [**`expon(..)`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.expon.html) function takes as parameters `loc` and `scale` (which correspond to the mean and the standard deviation. Since the standard deviation is the inverse of the variance, we thus can construct such distribution with:

```
B = stats.expon(scale=1/0.0035)
```

Then the cummulative distribution function says for `P(X < 100)`:

```
>>> print(B.cdf(100))
0.2953119102812866
```

Comment: Oh waw thank you a lot ! It is so great, thanks 100 times Willem !